# (ERROR) A value of type 'Adhan' can't be returned from the method 'getAdhan' because it has a return type of 'Future<List<Adhan>?>'

Tags: flutter, flutter-http

this code is for fetching data from json api , there is just one error in the code , and this is the error :

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH0Eb.png)

```
 class RemoteService {
  Future<List<Adhan>?> getAdhan() async {
    var client = http.Client();

    var uri = Uri.parse("https://api.pray.zone/v2/times/today.json?city=paris");
    var response = await client.get(uri);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var json = response.body;
      return adhanFromJson(json);
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to search in the Internet and YouTube for any problem similar to my problem, I did not find anything to help me.
how can i fix this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function named `adhanFromJson` probably returns a `Adhan`, while `getAdhan` expects you to return a `List<Adhan>` or `null`.

Either change the return type of `getAdhan` or return a `List<Adhan>`.